# Set Python project root in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, python.el

[**emacs-for-python**](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python) (based on `python.el`) provides nice capability to start Python process and send buffer there right from Emacs (normally you do it with `C-c C-c`). However, this way **new process** is created for **every buffer**, and Python's **working directory** is set to the **directory of corresponding file**.

Instead, I'd like to have single Python process with **working directory** set to the **root of the project**. Or maybe even several processes, but started at the root directory, not the directory of the module.

---

Why do I need it? It's all about imports. Imagine following project structure:

```
myproject
   package1
      __init__.py
      mod1.py
   package2
      __init__.py
      mod2.py
```

If I start Python process on file `mod1.py`, Emacs will automatically set working directory to `myproject/package1` so that I will be restricted to importing modules from the same package only. No imports from other packages. No absolute imports. Pain.

Currently I use a trick with `sys.path`, something like:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '..', '..'))
```

at the beginning of each module. But this is really, really, really ugly and inconvenient.

So does anybody have any tips or tricks to set up Python's project root for inferior process in Emacs?

Comment: Hi, is there a way you detect the `project` for a given file? What I mean is suppose you are in `mod1.py` can you detect that the project is `myproject`?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: I was thinking about walking up directory tree and checking for `__init__.py` file. The first directory without this file may be considered as a project root (at least it will give correct names for package hierarchy starting from the first available package). But in fact, I'm more interested in _how to force python to start from specific directory_. Knowing this, I can overload corresponding function to calculate project path in a way that fits my needs best.

Comment: One way I can think of is using `inferior-python-mode-hook` give me some time I will write the required elisp and get back to you. BTW you meant `The first directory **with** this file may be considered as a project root` didn't you?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: I see project root as a parent directory for all top-level packages. In an example in my question, top directories with `__init__.py` are `package1` and `package2`, but project root is in `myproject`. Setting it as a python working directory allows to use absolute imports like `import package1.mod1`.

Comment: Alright I have added an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this should get you started

```
(defvar my-python-shell-dir-setup-code 
  "import os
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
while os.path.isfile('__init__.py') and (os.getcwd() != home):
    os.chdir('..')
del os")

(defun my-python-shell-dir-setup ()
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (python-shell-send-string my-python-shell-dir-setup-code process)
    (message "Setup project path")))

(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook 'my-python-shell-dir-setup)
```

Here is what we are doing `my-python-shell-dir-setup-code` is simple python code to find `project-dir` and set it (it quick and dirty you may want to modify it according to your needs). Then we add a `inferior-python-mode-hook` (i.e. `my-shell-dir-setup`) to execute the python code in out inferior shell whenever the shell is created.

Comment: Very smart! Though, I whould use `os.path.exists` instead of `os.path.isfile`, which seems a bit misleading. Anyway, thanks a lot! One more step on the way to a perfect Python environment :)

Comment: I thought checking whether a file of name `__init__.py` exists would be more approriate, anyways I glad that this helped you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with emacs-for-python, but finding the path to the root of your project is straightforward.

Projectile provides a function `projectile-project-root`. You could call this in your mod1.py buffer, and it will return `"/path/to/myproject"`. This assumes that projectile can recognise your project root, which will be fine if you've using some sort of VCS.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in fact I'm more interested specifically in how to _set_ project root (python working directory) in epy/package.el, and not how to _calculate_ it. On other hand, projetile itself looks interesting, so thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer is correct, except there is a bug in the accepted answer above. The correct solution to the question posed is:

```
(defvar my-python-shell-dir-setup-code 
"import os
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
while (not os.path.isfile('__init__.py')) and (os.getcwd() != home):
    os.chdir('..')
del os")

(defun my-python-shell-dir-setup ()
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (python-shell-send-string my-python-shell-dir-setup-code process)
    (message "Setup project path")))

(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook 'my-python-shell-dir-setup)
```

The difference is that the line
`while os.path.isfile('__init__.py') and (os.getcwd() != home):` should be `while (not os.path.isfile('__init__.py')) and (os.getcwd() != home):`

We want to step back a directory if there is NOT an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32197260)