# Emacs 24 with Elpy 1.7.50 does not recognize Python Project

Tags: python, emacs

I'm in the process of converting over from using Eclipse to Emacs 24.3 and Elpy 1.7.50 for my Python development.  However, I'm running into a roadblock in getting Elpy to recognize my project.  Based on my understanding of the way elpy should work from the [documentation](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html), if I set a project root folder, that folder should be included in the `sys.path` to search for modules.  This is not happening.

The [Elpy Documentation](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) doesn't seem to have any answers to my particular conundrum, nor can I find a basic tutorial that walks me through creating my first Elpy project to break it down and show me what I'm doing wrong.

In the shell, I first create the virtual environment `virtualenv` using
`mkvirtualenv` from `virtualenvwrapper`.  Then I create the following
folder/file structure within the virtualenv folder:

```
virtualenv/
└─ my_project/
   ├─ src/
   │  └─ my_project/
   │     ├─ __init__.py
   │     └─ foo.py
   └─ test/
```

The contents of `foo.py` are:

```
class foo(object):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Next, I connect to an already-running instance of Emacs server using the Emacs client. Within Emacs, I enter:

```
M-x pyvenv-workon virtualenv
```

Emacs does show `[my_project]` in the mode line.  Next, I enter:

```
M-x elpy-set-project-root ~/Projects/my_project/src
```

Then, I type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> to search the project for a file, and I get:

```
C-c C-f is undefined
```

So, I type:

```
M-x elpy-find-file
```

and I get:

```
No project root found
```

If I create the file `test/test_foo.py` with the following code:

```
from my_project import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

and then run it using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>, I get:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/doug/Projects/my_project/src/test/test_foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_project import foo
ImportError: No module named 'my_project'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing projectile? It solved similar problems at https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/957 and [Set Python project root in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256188/set-python-project-root-in-emacs).

You can install projectile via emacs's package manager:

<kbd>M-x package-list-packages</kbd>, select projectile (shorthands: <kbd>i x</kbd> to mark as install, and execute).

Comment: Coudl please add some more context to the question itself, rather than links? For example, how to install projectile (assuming it's installable over pip or similar).

Comment: @chade_: It is installable inside emacs. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Could you review `~/.emacs.d/elpa/find-file-in-project-3.3/find-file-in-project.el` please. There are several strings about project definition criteria and I've found:

```
(require 'cl)
(defvar ffip-project-file ".git"
  "The file that should be used to define a project root.
```

I've tested M-x elpy-set-project-root and M-x elpy-find-file inside my git repo and it works (with several quirks:-).

In other words: *feel free to customize it by yourself.*